# Finding a complete subgraph efficiently

Tags: algorithm, graphs-and-networks

I'm working on some experimental algorithms which would benefit from methods to find an instance of complete subgraphs with N vertices in an undirected graph. This far I've tried these methods:

- `FindClique`: apparently this doesn't work because Mathematica returns only maximal cliques. Try `FindClique[CompleteGraph@5, {3}]`, for instance.

  **EDIT**: Inspired by belisarius' comment, this does work:

  ```
  findCompleteSubgraph[graph_Graph, size_Integer] := 
    Subgraph[graph, 
     Take[Flatten@FindClique[graph, {size, VertexCount@graph}], 
      UpTo@size]];
  ```

  ... but isn't really faster than my naive algorithm below. The problem is that it finds the largest, not the the first (sub)clique of size `size`, and this can take quite a bit of time on an almost complete graph.
- Simplistic method trying to find exactly N vertices which have edge between each of them, using `SatisfiabilityInstances`, `BooleanCountingFunction` and regular Boolean expressions. Although this seems like an elegant solution, it's too slow and doesn't scale.
- Search using adjacency matrix converted to a list of bit-vectors, traversing the graph for a candidate using `BitAnd` instead of `Intersection` and population count function instead of `Length`. Essentially a harder-to-understand variation of the last method, but with the same run-time complexity.
- My best attempt, a very naive recursive graph traversal algorithm outlined here (with a benchmark for much smaller graphs than which I plan to use in real life):

  ```
  Module[
   {traverseStep, findCompleteSubgraph},

   traverseStep[graph_Graph, size_Integer, visited_List, 
      sharedadj_List] /; Length@sharedadj < size := Null;
   traverseStep[graph_Graph, size_Integer, visited_List, 
      sharedadj_List] /; Length@visited == size := Throw@visited;
   traverseStep[graph_Graph, size_Integer, visited_List, 
      sharedadj_List] :=
    (traverseStep[graph, size, Append[visited, #],
         Intersection[Append[RandomSample@AdjacencyList[graph, #], #], 
         sharedadj]] & /@ Complement[sharedadj, visited];
     Throw@{});

   findCompleteSubgraph[graph_Graph, size_Integer] := 
    Subgraph[graph, 
     Catch[traverseStep[graph, size, {#}, 
         Append[RandomSample@AdjacencyList[graph, #], #]] & /@ 
       VertexList[graph]]];

  {Mean@#, Histogram@#} &@(First@Timing@findCompleteSubgraph[#, 5] & /@ 
      Table[RandomGraph[{3000, Floor[3000^2/3]}], {50}])]
  ```

  [image]

Can you think of a more efficient, preferably concise algorithm? Have I possibly missed an internal method for this task?

Comment: A clique of size `m>n`is also a clique of size `n` by just removing the surplus vertices. So you can use `FindClique[g]` and check if the result is a list of length greater than 5. This looks faster.

Comment: Perhaps more to the point: `FindClique[CompleteGraph[7], {5}]` doesn't work, but `FindClique[CompleteGraph[7]]` does

Comment: Thinking again, not sure if this is much faster. But at least it is easier :)

Comment: I could add this to IGraph/M, but it wouldn't help: there is not way to quickly extract the internal representation of a Mathematica graph (even though I *know* it's there), so just transferring `g = RandomGraph[{3000, Floor[3000^2/3]}];` to igraph ends up taking a full second.  That's partly because `EdgeList[g]; // AbsoluteTiming` --> 0.4 s.  `AdjacencyMatrix[g]["NonzeroPositions"]; // AbsoluteTiming` is 0.06 s, but that method is not general enough to support everything ...

Comment: @Szabolcs I gather you know IGraph has functionality for this; can you point me towards their implementation?

Comment: @kirma I'm [in the process](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/pull/888) of updating the igraph implementation to the the Cliquer library.  But I don't know how the algorithm works.  If you're looking for a library, Cliquer can do this, it has a function exactly for finding *just one* not-necessarily-maximal clique.  You could write a LibraryLink interface to Cliquer.  To make it fast, use the  `AdjacencyMatrix[g]["NonzeroPositions"]` method to extract the edge list and send it as an `MTensor` with `"Constant"` passing, then convert to Cliquer format on the C side.

Comment: There's still no guarantee that it will be faster than your pure-Mathematica implementation, due to all the graph-format-conversions that need to happen ... However, if you want to use Cliquer from C and not Mathematica, I heartily recommend it!

Comment: @Szabolcs I converted the routine in Cliquer to Mathematica just to check out how it performs. Unfortunately the news are that it doesn't perform very well. Without conversion of the graph to bit-vector adjacency matrix form routines are tediously slow either in dense or sparse graphs, no matter what tricks I attempt to play, and conversion itself would just move the performance hog from one place to another. The version in my answer below performs surprisingly well, although it has no smarts at all...

Comment: @kirma I guess that's because just copying such a large graph takes time.  `AdjacencyMatrix[g]["NonzeroPositions"]; // Timing` alone is 0.05 s for your test graph, must slower than your function. Even `GraphComputation`CloneGraph[g]; // Timing` is slower than your function, and that's likely the most efficient possible copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Mma v13 features a new function called `FindIsomorphicSubgraph`, which seems suitable, and a much more efficient solution than my code below for this task. Just use `FindIsomorphicSubgraph[#, CompleteGraph[5], 1] &` instead of `findCompleteSubgraph[#, 5] &`. This would appear to be about 20 times faster for the dense graph example below, and about 2000 times faster for the sparse graph example!

**Original answer**:

This is a trivial implementation that searches all possible `size`-length paths in subgraphs that are complete during the search. Intersections of vertex lists are used to decide traversal path. Once sufficiently long path is found, `Throw` is used to exit recursive calls.

```
Module[{traverseStep, findCompleteSubgraph},
 traverseStep[graph_Graph, found_List, size_Integer, 
   vertexlist_List] :=
  (If[size <= 0, Throw@found];
   Do[
    traverseStep[graph, Append[found, vertexlist[[pos]]], size - 1, 
     Intersection[Drop[vertexlist, pos], 
      AdjacencyList[graph, vertexlist[[pos]]]]],
    {pos, Length@vertexlist}]);
 
 findCompleteSubgraph[graph_Graph, size_Integer] :=
  Subgraph[graph,
   Catch@(traverseStep[graph, {}, size, VertexList@graph]; 
     Throw@{})];
 
 {Mean@#, Histogram@#} &@(First@Timing@findCompleteSubgraph[#, 5] & /@
     Table[RandomGraph[{3000, Floor[3000^2/3]}], {200}])]
```

[image]

This also works reasonably on sparse graphs:

```
{Mean@#, Histogram@#} &@(First@Timing@findCompleteSubgraph[#, 5] & /@ 
   Table[RandomGraph[{3000, Floor[3000^2/50]}], {200}])
```

[image]

A highlighted example:

```
HighlightGraph[#, findCompleteSubgraph[#, 6]] &@RandomGraph[{12, 50}]
```

[image]