# Trim graph to fully connected components?

Tags: function-construction, graphs-and-networks

Given a graph like e.g.,

```
gr = Graph[{UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[1, 4], UndirectedEdge[2, 4], 
     UndirectedEdge[3, 4], UndirectedEdge[1, 5], UndirectedEdge[2, 6], 
     UndirectedEdge[3, 6]}]
```

> [image]

I would like to have a function `trim` that would remove vertices from this graph  such that a maximum number of vertices remains which are all connected to each other:

```
gr2 = trim[gr]
gr2//FullForm
```

> [image]
>   `Graph[List[1,2,3,4],List[UndirectedEdge[1,2],UndirectedEdge[1,3],UndirectedEdge[2,3],UndirectedEdge[1,4],UndirectedEdge[2,4],UndirectedEdge[3,4]]]`

Does Mathematica have such a function? Or is there a quick way to write it using Mathematica functionality? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What you are looking for is a clique, and finding a maximal clique can be accomplished with `FindClique`, if you are after that. This can be very computationally intensive. If you are looking for a clique of certain size there wouldn't appear to be a built-in function. I did ponder about the problem in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97725/finding-a-complete-subgraph-efficiently ...

Comment: @kirma IGraph/M can find cliques of a given size (not necessarily maximal) very efficiently: `IGCliques`.

Comment: The question is unclear. *"remove all vertices from this graph which are not fully connected to all other vertices"* --> Why did you not remove vertex `1`? It is not connected to all other vertices. It is not connected to `6`.

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is a clique cover, i.e. partitioning the vertices into cliques? IGraph/M has `IGCliqueCover`. Be sure to look it up in the documentation which discusses the `Method` option.

Comment: @kirma Thank you, I'll take a look at FindClique. The maximal one should be sufficient for me.

Comment: @Szabolcs You are right, what I meant is that I'd like to have the graph trimmed so that a maximum number of vertices remains which are all connected to each other, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to have a function trim that would remove vertices from this graph such that a maximum number of vertices remains which are all connected to each other:

You are looking for a largest [clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)). It can be done with

```
FindClique[g]
```

To find all largest cliques, use

```
FindClique[g, Length /@ FindClique[g], All]
```

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) also has a function for this, `IGLargestCliques`, and several other clique-related functions.  For example, you can partition the graph into a smallest number of cliques:

```
SeedRandom[123]
g = RandomGraph[{10, 40}]

HighlightGraph[
 Graph[g, EdgeStyle -> LightGray],
 Style[Subgraph[g, #], Thick] & /@ IGCliqueCover[g]
]
```

[image]

As in this example, some of the components may have only one vertex. Also note that the components may not be largest or even maximal cliques.  What this function does is it tries to minimize the number of components, not maximize the size of the largest component. If you want the largest component to be as large as possible, you could use

```
comps = First@
  Last@Reap@
    NestWhile[VertexDelete[#, Sow@First@FindClique[#]] &, g, 
     VertexCount[#] > 0 &]

(* {{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10}, {2, 9}, {8}} *)

HighlightGraph[
 Graph[g, EdgeStyle -> LightGray],
 Style[Subgraph[g, #], Thick] & /@ comps
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a link to the IGraph/M? I seem to be finding somewhat unrelated things when googling for it.

Comment: @Kagaratsch Added link. What did you find when you googled?  IGraph/M is not needed for this though. If all you want is a largest clique, you can just use `FindClique`.